# AngularJS interceptor retry request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, request, interceptor

Hello im developing an Angular Application and im having few problems trying to make a retry for the latest request that has been made within an http interceptor.
I have this interceptor for authentication validation on each request, and also i have it on the response for token expirations. The thing is that when my token expires i need to fire a refresh token for it to get the new access, and if its succesfull then i retry the intercepted request.

Everything is working correctly. but... i have multiple rejected calls with 401 and when i try to log (you can see the console.log message). it seems that only the first call that is rejected is firing the refresh token request. What would be a best approach or something that can make it work? Ty in advance.

```
var _responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        var authService = $injector.get('authService');
        var state = $injector.get('$state');
        var http = $injector.get('$http');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (rejection.data && rejection.data.ErrorCode == errorCodes.missingRole){
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
        //var authData = localStorageService.get(authConstant.cookieName);
        var authData = authService.getAuth();
        if (authData) {
               return authService.refreshToken().then(function (response) {
                       console.log("call is: ", rejection);
                    if (response.access_token){
                        //Todo: find a method to resend last request;
                        return http(rejection.config);
                    }
                },
                function (err) {
                    state.go('app.login');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                });
        }
        authService.logOut();
        state.go('app.login');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had similar problem. My code is a bit different, but the idea is the same, try this

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
authService.refreshToken().then(function () {
        $http(errorResponse.config).then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
    }, function () {
        authService.logOut().then(deferred.reject);
    });

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i've finally managed to solve it using a request buffer

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it using an http buffer to store all future rejected calls to the backend.
The buffer code is here: 
https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/master/src/http-auth-interceptor.js

and i've slightly modified it to get it working, here is the modified version:

```
angular.module('authModule').factory('httpBufferService', ['$injector', function($injector) {
/** Holds all the requests, so they can be re-requested in future. */
var buffer = [];
var doAction=false;
/** Service initialized later because of circular dependency problem. */
var $http;

function retryHttpRequest(config, deferred) {
    function successCallback(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }
    function errorCallback(response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
    }
    $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
    $http(config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
var bufferData = {
    getItems:function (){
        return buffer;
    },
        /**
         * Appends HTTP request configuration object with deferred response attached to buffer.
         */
    append: function(config, deferred) {
        buffer.push({
            config: config,
            deferred: deferred
        });
    },

    /**
     * Abandon or reject (if reason provided) all the buffered requests.
     */
    rejectAll: function(reason) {
        if (reason) {
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
                buffer[i].deferred.reject(reason);
            }
        }
        buffer = [];
    },
    clean:function(){
        buffer = [];
        doAction = false;
    },
    /**
     * Retries all the buffered requests clears the buffer.
     */
    retryAll: function() {
        if (!doAction){
            doAction = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
                retryHttpRequest(buffer[i].config, buffer[i].deferred);
            }
            bufferData.clean();
        }

    }
};
return bufferData;
}]);
```

and this is the implementation:

```
var authData = authService.getAuth();
httpBuffer.append(rejection.config,defer);
if (httpBuffer.getItems().length>1){
    return defer.promise;
}
if (authData) {
   return authService.refreshToken().then(function (response) {
        if (response.access_token){
            httpBuffer.retryAll();
            return defer.promise;            
        }
    },
    function (err) {        
        httpBuffer.clean();
        authService.logOut();        
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    });
}
httpBuffer.clean();
```